# Checking if Android phone is simulator or real device

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

Like in Blackberry, do we have any API method (similar to `DeviceInfo.isSimulator()`) to check if device is simulator or real device?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I detect the Android emulator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799097/how-can-i-detect-the-android-emulator)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a 100% correct way to do this since the internal constants seem to change every once in a while. This works for me though:

```
if (android.os.Build.MODEL.contains("google_sdk") ||
    android.os.Build.MODEL.contains("Emulator")) {
    // Then you are running the app on the emulator.
}
```

Comment: Other suggestions can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799097/how-can-i-detect-when-an-android-application-is-running-in-the-emulator?answertab=votes#tab-top