# android is it possible for an app to detect when it is running on emulator vs device

Tags: android, android-emulator

I develop a game that is heavily dependent upon timing, when I run it in the emulator it executes understandably slower than when I run it on my phone. This forces me to up all the "stats" in my game, so that I can actually "beat it" when I am developing - when Debugging, the game is unwinnable.

Is there a call, or variable, or something that I can use to determine whether I am currently running on the Emulator and not a device.

I've considered trying to detect if `Framerate` is low.
I've considered trying to read the "device name" from some sort of build in system field.

But neither seems like a very good method to pursue.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Have a look at [thread discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2799097/593709) on detecting emulator

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Build.DEVICE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#DEVICE) value and compare to "sdk".

Answer (score 1):

First idea:check the network operator, on the emulator, it's always equal to "Android". Not documented and just a guess that it will work everytime!

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String networkOperator = tm.getNetworkOperatorName();
if("Android".equals(networkOperator)) {
    // Emulator
}
else {
    // Device
}
```

Second idea: the manufacturer:

```
public boolean isEmulator() {
    return Build.MANUFACTURER.equals("unknown");
}
```

Third idea: seem th best one, check the debug key:

```
static final String DEBUGKEY = 
      "get the debug key from logcat after calling the function below once from the emulator"; 




public static boolean signedWithDebugKey(Context context, Class<?> cls) 
{
    boolean result = false;
    try {
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context, cls);
        PackageInfo pinfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(comp.getPackageName(),PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        Signature sigs[] = pinfo.signatures;
        for ( int i = 0; i < sigs.length;i++)
        Log.d(TAG,sigs[i].toCharsString());
        if (DEBUGKEY.equals(sigs[0].toCharsString())) {
            result = true;
            Log.d(TAG,"package has been signed with the debug key");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG,"package signed with a key other than the debug key");
        }

    } catch (android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }

    return result;

}
```

from here: [How can I detect when an Android application is running in the emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799097/how-can-i-detect-when-an-android-application-is-running-in-the-emulator)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Google APIs, you want:

```
"google_sdk".equals( Build.PRODUCT );
```

If not, you'll want to use:

```
"sdk".equals( Build.PRODUCT );
```

The older (since deprecated) way to do this was to check `ANDROID_ID`, which is null on the AVD, but this doesn't work on API 7 and above:

```
// ONLY WORKS ON 2.1 AND BELOW

 String android_id = Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID); 
  if (android_id == null) { 
      // Emulator!  
  } else { 
      // Device
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Dan S** gave a good answer about how to detect when running on the emulator. However, a few tips:

1. Instead of relying on something in the SDK, why not just set up your own flag? Just keep a `public final static boolean isEmulator` that you change from `true` to `false` depending on the environment, and build your code with ifs and elses around it. The `Build.DEVICE` method is not 100% safe, since some rooted devices might have that borked.
2. Low framerate detection could be a good thing to implement. Given the wide range of Android devices, it might prove helpful on lower-end ones.