# Determine if emulator device is in use

Tags: android, android-emulator

Does anyone know what the method `hasClients` does in the android sdk?

`boolean com.android.ddmlib.IDevice.hasClients()`

It doesn't look like its documented.

I am trying to find a way to see if an emulator is being used. Any good way to do this?

```
for(int i =0; i < devices.length; i++){

    if(!devices[i].hasClients()){

        monkeyDevice = devices[i];

    }

}
```

When I say is being used, I mean if there is currently an application running on the device or if its receiving commands from anything.

### Update

I should of mentioned that I want to test for these conditions **outside** from my application. I have a seperate class running outside the application that starts the application within an available emulator. I want this monkey class to know if an existing emulator is already being used for testing.

Comment: Probably http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799097/how-can-i-detect-when-an-android-application-is-running-in-the-emulator will be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this question to figure out if you are running in the emulator:
[How can I detect when an Android application is running in the emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799097/how-can-i-detect-when-an-android-application-is-running-in-the-emulator)

On a monkey-related point, you might want to have a look at [Activity.isUserAMonkey()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#isUserAMonkey%28%29) method (since API level 8, OS 2.2).  The Google [DeviceAdminSample code](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/DeviceAdminSample.html) gives a brief explanation:

```
/**
 * If the "user" is a monkey, post an alert and notify the caller.  This prevents automated
 * test frameworks from stumbling into annoying or dangerous operations.
 */
private static boolean alertIfMonkey(Context context, int stringId) {
    if (ActivityManager.isUserAMonkey()) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setMessage(stringId);
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.monkey_ok, null);
        builder.show();
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```