# How can I limit my android application installed on real device only?

Tags: android, android-emulator, apk, android-install-apk

I expect that my android application is allowed to install only on real device, and android-emulator can't.How can I limit my android application installed on real device only ? 
Thanks for any replies.

Comment: [This can be helpful for you](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2799097/593709)

Comment: its depend on app memory and total memory of device

Comment: Can you tell us why would you need such a requirement? Just curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's one way how to handle it. Just check device id (IMEI code). For emulator it's always `null`, so you can define either someone tries to launch it in real device or in emulator.

```
    TelephonyManager tm=(TelephonyManager )activity.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if(tm==null || !this.hasTelephony())
    {
        Log.v(TAG, "Can't get telephony service. Forcing shut down!");
        return false;
    }
    String deviceId=tm.getDeviceId();
    if(deviceId==null || deviceId.length() < 2)
    {
        Log.v(TAG, "Looks like emulator - bail out!");
        Toast.makeText(activity, "This special version not intended to run in this device!", 5000).show();
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Actually the imei/device id for our emulator is 000000000.... I think 15 zeros overall. So null or two zeros wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot stop people from installing in emulator, but if you have [Google Licensing](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/licensing-service-for-android.html) installed it will make sure that it does not run on unlicensed devices.