# how to determine whether apk is running on emulator or real device?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I would like to prevent user from registering on emulator, so how to determine whether apk is running on emulator or real device? Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps check if Google Play is installed? It's hard as hell to install Google Play in an emulator

Comment: Haven't tried any of the solutions, but [start here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799097/how-can-i-detect-when-an-android-application-is-running-in-the-emulator). Keep in mind that no methods are full proof.

Comment: Maybe this will help:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799097/how-can-i-detect-when-an-android-application-is-running-in-the-emulator][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799097/how-can-i-detect-when-an-android-application-is-running-in-the-emulator

Comment: In general the system propery Google uses is "ro.kernel.qemu". If this returns "1" then you are running on an emulator

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21505193/878126

Answer (score 0):

You can check the device id which is hardcoded into emulator.
For checking :

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
Log.e("id", telephonyManager.getDeviceId());
```

And the result should be something like this:

```
03-12 09:50:08.043: E/id(447): 000000000000000
```

With permission

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (Build.BRAND.equalsIgnoreCase("generic")) {
                 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "YES, I am an emulator", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           } else {
               Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "NO, I am NOT an emulator", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }
```