# Is there a method to detect an emulator except using BUILD?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have an android application. I want it to run differently when it runs on an emulator. So to detect an emulator from the code, I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799097/how-can-i-detect-when-an-android-application-is-running-in-the-emulator)! But all the solutions given here are using BUILD class to detect which doesn't work on all emulators. So is there any other method to detect an emulator from the code?