# Block emulators in android application

Tags: android, security, android-emulator, android-sensors

For the security purpose, I want to block emulator to use my app.
I do not want my app to be installed on any emulator like genymotion,bluestack,droidx etc...

I have an app where we have offer wall which contains no of android app, that use can install and earn points. Once they earn some points then they can withdraw using paypal account.

Now the problem is some of the users are installing it via proxy or emulator.they are earning money like anything by using proxy or emulator..

Please help..I am in big trouble..

Comment: Please elaborate on your trouble. Interesting!

Comment: `Block emulators in android application`. No. You want to block your app if it is on an emulator.

Comment: i want to block my app on emulator to get installed...

Comment: Preventing to install will not go i think. I second Rohit5k2 in refusing to run.

Answer (score 2):

I think this would work. When your app starts check this method. If it returns `true`, exit your app. Otherwise continue. It won't prevent from installing but sure would prevent from running.

```
 public static boolean isRunningOnEmulator()
 {
    boolean result=
        Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("generic")
            ||Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("unknown")
            ||Build.MODEL.contains("google_sdk")
            ||Build.MODEL.contains("Emulator")
            ||Build.MODEL.contains("Android SDK built for x86")
            ||Build.MANUFACTURER.contains("Genymotion");
    if(result)
        return true;

    result|=Build.BRAND.startsWith("generic") && Build.DEVICE.startsWith("generic");

    if(result)
        return true;

    result|="google_sdk".equals(Build.PRODUCT);

    return result;
}
```

More information is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799097/how-can-i-detect-when-an-android-application-is-running-in-the-emulator)

Comment: is it possible to change fingerprint configuration in emulator?.....other setting like model,manufacturer etc already using....hackers are modifying the details and running app on emulator...

Comment: I don't think so. But I can't be 100% sure.

Comment: this code working but hacker has changed the value of Build product