# Android - how to detect if app running on Nox emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I don't want to allow my users to run my app on an emulator.

I have succeeded detecting any other emulator, except *Nox app player*.

Check my solutions here: [How can I detect when an Android application is running in the emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799097/how-can-i-detect-when-an-android-application-is-running-in-the-emulator/35440927#35440927)

Nox emulator has same device data as an actual phone, they even simulate deviceId (IMEI number, it is not `000000000000` and nut null), and network operator name. Looks like every time I launch the Nox app player, it randomizes all the `Build.PRODUCT` and similar fields.

Although there is a pattern, some of the fields have incompatible names, like the manufacturer is sony, but device model is HTC...

Comment: how did you solve your problem?

Comment: @Daryn, i didn't, i have found no solution for this so far.

Comment: @lxknvlk did you find the solution?

Comment: @mdh.heydari no

Answer (score 0):

Check `BASEBAND` version os the device. In case of Nox player the baseband version is null. In the android devices you will get the `BASEBAND` version value.

Since **SDK Lvl 14** you should use `Build.getRadioVersion()` in order to retrieve the baseband version.

Comment: Is this reliable?

Comment: For most of the android devices Yes its reliable. But check as per your requirement.. I have testing this on multiple devices and emulator. This seems to be sufficient for my requirement. Let me know if this works for you

Answer (score 0):

Confirm that the phone does not have these 3 apps installed com.vphone.googlesign com.vphone.helper and com.vphone.launcher