# Run Android app Only on Physical Device not Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb, emulation

> How can I make my app run only on a physical android device, not an emulator.

When the app starts I want to check if the device is a physical device or emulator.  If it is an emulator, I want my app to stop.

How can I do this?

Comment: Turn off Emulator

Comment: Are you asking how to make the app not run in an emulator when you launch it, or how to keep other people from being able to run your app in an emulator?

Comment: ya.. I want prevent other people run app on emulator

Answer (score 7):

In the `onCreate()` method of your launch activity, you can check whether the device is running on an emulator and, if it is, just call `finish()`. To check whether you're running on an emulator, you can use something like the following code (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21505193/535871)):

```
public static boolean isEmulator() {
    return Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("generic")
            || Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("unknown")
            || Build.MODEL.contains("google_sdk")
            || Build.MODEL.contains("Emulator")
            || Build.MODEL.contains("Android SDK built for x86")
            || Build.MANUFACTURER.contains("Genymotion")
            || (Build.BRAND.startsWith("generic") && Build.DEVICE.startsWith("generic"))
            || "google_sdk".equals(Build.PRODUCT);
}
```

You can find lots of other suggestions on the web for detecting an emulator environment. I don't know of any that are absolutely foolproof, but the above is pretty robust.

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like below

```
boolean isEmulator() {
        return (Build.BRAND.startsWith("generic") && Build.DEVICE.startsWith("generic"))
                || Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("generic")
                || Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("unknown")
                || Build.HARDWARE.contains("goldfish")
                || Build.HARDWARE.contains("ranchu")
                || Build.HARDWARE.equals("vbox86")
                || Build.HARDWARE.toLowerCase().contains("nox")
                || Build.MODEL.contains("google_sdk")
                || Build.MODEL.contains("Emulator")
                || Build.MODEL.contains("Android SDK built for x86")
                || Build.MODEL.toLowerCase().contains("droid4x")
                || Build.MANUFACTURER.contains("Genymotion")
                || Build.PRODUCT.contains("sdk_google")
                || Build.PRODUCT.contains("google_sdk")
                || Build.PRODUCT.contains("sdk")
                || Build.PRODUCT.contains("sdk_x86")
                || Build.PRODUCT.contains("vbox86p")
                || Build.PRODUCT.contains("emulator")
                || Build.PRODUCT.contains("simulator")
                || Build.PRODUCT.toLowerCase().contains("nox")
                || Build.BOARD.toLowerCase().contains("nox")
                || Build.BOOTLOADER.toLowerCase().contains("nox")
                || Build.SERIAL.toLowerCase().contains("nox");
    }
```

It's an update of the code used in the Flutter project(device info plugin). check it [here](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/device_info/device_info/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/deviceinfo/MethodCallHandlerImpl.java#L115-L131)