# Detect if game running in android emulator

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, emulation, virtual

Is there any way to know the game is running in an emulator application or a real device ?

Some Applications like `VirtualXposed` are virtual emulator for android devices. Such Applications allow users to install a game / application multiple times on their device with different identifies.

I want to know is there any way to recognize my game / application is running in emulator or a physical device in unity3d ?

something like :

```
if(isemulator)
   {
       dosomething();
   }
```

Comment: Not sure, it looks like some other people also have the same question (but no answers) on the unity answer hub. I found this on how to detect if an .apk is running on an emulator: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799097/how-can-i-detect-when-an-android-application-is-running-in-the-emulator

Comment: I want a simple solution @Katianie

Comment: A "simple" solution likely does not exist. Mainly because an application should not know or care if its on an emulator.

Comment: @iman_sh (please be polite) That was the most simple solution I could find. What your asking is not typical. Why do you need to know its an emulator?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not easy to do since there are many emulators out there. The answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5864867/3785314) post says that you can use `Build.FINGERPRINT.contains("generic")` to do that.

You can port the Java code to C# in Unity with the `AndroidJavaClass` class and without building Java plugin. Below is the ported version in C#:

```
public bool IsEmulator()
{
    AndroidJavaClass osBuild;
    osBuild = new AndroidJavaClass("android.os.Build");
    string fingerPrint = osBuild.GetStatic<string>("FINGERPRINT");
    return fingerPrint.Contains("generic");
}
```

---

To make sure that this covers most emulator, use the [*android-emulator-detector*](https://github.com/framgia/android-emulator-detector) plugin. This plugin seems to be rigorously tested and detects most emulators.  You can use `AndroidJavaClass` to communicate with it and `UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage` to make callback into your Unity code in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can look for some emulator specific SystemInfos ([Unity Docs SystemInfo](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SystemInfo.html)) eg. SystemInfo.deviceModel