# Can you detect whether your android app is being run in emulator?

Tags: android

How would you detect programatically whether your application was being run by virtualization environment such as parallels?

Comment: Can you clarify the requirement as [How can I detect when an Android application is running in the emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2799097/295004) should answer the question.

Comment: thanks for the response.. that url is helpful.  need to programatically check whether my app has been launched within an emulator such as parallels or bluestacks