# Nativescript: how to use different environment vars for an emulator and a real device?

Tags: android, webpack, nativescript

I'm building a project with Nativescript-Vue. I have standard a setup with Webpack.

I understand that i can pass different vars, using something like this:

> tns build android --bundle --env.development --env.property=value

How can i "distinguish" between the two different platforms(emulator and a real device, they are both "development"), in order to pass different API url's?

Comment: If you want to distinguish between device and emulator, you are suppose to do that at run time not at compilation / build time.

Comment: Even better. How can i do it?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this,

```
        if (isIOS) {
            const description = String(NSString.stringWithUTF8String(NXGetLocalArchInfo()[0].description));
            this.isSimulator = description.indexOf("x86") !== -1 || description.indexOf("i386") !== -1;
        }
        if (isAndroid) {
            this.isSimulator = android.os.Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("generic")
                || android.os.Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("unknown")
                || android.os.Build.MODEL.indexOf("google_sdk") !== -1
                || android.os.Build.MODEL.indexOf("Emulator") !== -1
                || android.os.Build.MODEL.indexOf("Android SDK built for x86") !== -1
                || android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER.indexOf("Genymotion") !== -1
                || (android.os.Build.BRAND.startsWith("generic") && android.os.Build.DEVICE.startsWith("generic"))
                || android.os.Build.PRODUCT === "google_sdk";
        }
```

The Android version is almost same as the one @Narendra linked in his answer but more of the NativeScript / JavaScript version.

[Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=m4hd4m)

Answer (score 1):

You can check the [Build](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html) properties from `android.os.Build` and see if Build.BRAND.startsWith("generic") or  Build.DEVICE.startsWith("generic")) or Build.PRODUCT.contains("emulator").

You may refer to few more properties as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21505193/3840213).