# Disable sensors in android emulator

Tags: android

I've created a virtual device in AVD with a new hardware profile with sensors disabled. I'm then checking both getDefaultSensor for null and also PackageManager.FEATURE_SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER.

On the emulator with a no sensor hardware profile its reporting true for both.

```
Context context = mRegistrar.context();
SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) context.getSystemService(context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
Sensor sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);


PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
boolean hasAccelerometer = manager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER);

result.success(hasAccelerometer);
```

Sensor is not null and returns

```
{Sensor name="Goldfish 3-axis Magnetic field sensor", vendor="The Android Open Source Project", version=1, type=2, maxRange=2000.0, resolution=1.0, power=6.7, minDelay=10000}
```

There also doesn't appear to be an option for disabling sensors in the emulator settings menu either.

Is there a way for the emulator to report the same way it would if running on a device with no sensors?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there are ways to detect if your app is running on an emulated device: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13815880/3034696

Try `boolean hasAccelerometer = manager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER) && !sensor.getName().contains("Goldfish");`

Comment: yeah, i was wondering if goldfish was a reliable way of testing for the emulator. What i don't know though is what a real phone will receive.  I can only assume that if it contains Goldfish then thats the same as false?