# How to block android app from being opened on emulators?

Tags: android

I have an android app and I have some private information and when people run on emulators my android app they can see that information. Does anyone have a solution on how to block emulators from accessing my APK?

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: Do you use kotlin or java?

Comment: Depending on how sensitive the information is, be aware that there are multiple ways to access your APK. A device can be rooted, a check if it's an emulator can be spoofed, an APK can be decompiled.

Comment: @NatigBabayev I use Java And I have just started coding. so i dont have very knowldege. i run a live tv app  and people try to steal my info using emulators

Answer (score 2):

You can create class that extends [android.app.Application](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application). In that class, you can throw runtime exception to crash the app, [if app is running on emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55355049/4699509).

Note that, there's no bulletproof solution as anyone can decompile your app with free tools and remove those checks easily.

```java
import android.app.Application;
import android.os.Build;

public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        if (isEmulator()) throw new IllegalStateException();
    }

    private boolean isEmulator() {
        return (Build.BRAND.startsWith("generic") && Build.DEVICE.startsWith("generic"))
                || Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("generic")
                || Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("unknown")
                || Build.HARDWARE.contains("goldfish")
                || Build.HARDWARE.contains("ranchu")
                || Build.MODEL.contains("google_sdk")
                || Build.MODEL.contains("Emulator")
                || Build.MODEL.contains("Android SDK built for x86")
                || Build.MANUFACTURER.contains("Genymotion")
                || Build.PRODUCT.contains("sdk_google")
                || Build.PRODUCT.contains("google_sdk")
                || Build.PRODUCT.contains("sdk")
                || Build.PRODUCT.contains("sdk_x86")
                || Build.PRODUCT.contains("vbox86p")
                || Build.PRODUCT.contains("emulator")
                || Build.PRODUCT.contains("simulator");
    }
}
```

Also, do not forget to add that class to the `<application>` tag of your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.natigbabayev.stackoverflow">

    <application
        ...
        android:name=".App">
        ...
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I hope my answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

Updated version for 2021 and also detect VirtualBox:

```
/**
 * Class to detect if the user is running on an emulator
 *
 * Created by Benjamin Aimone on 16/12/2021.
 */
object EmulatorDetector {
    private var isRunningOnEmulator: Boolean? = null

    fun isRunningOnEmulator(): Boolean? {
        isRunningOnEmulator?.let {
            return it
        }
        // Android SDK emulator
        isRunningOnEmulator = runningOnAndroidStudioEmulator()
                || Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("generic")
                || Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("unknown")
                || Build.MODEL.contains("google_sdk")
                || Build.MODEL.contains("Emulator")
                || Build.MODEL.contains("Android SDK built for x86")
                || Build.MODEL.contains("VirtualBox")
                //bluestacks
                || "QC_Reference_Phone" == Build.BOARD && !"Xiaomi".equals(Build.MANUFACTURER, ignoreCase = true) //bluestacks
                || Build.MANUFACTURER.contains("Genymotion")
                || Build.HOST == "Build2" //MSI App Player
                || Build.BRAND.startsWith("generic") && Build.DEVICE.startsWith("generic")
                || Build.PRODUCT == "google_sdk"
                // another Android SDK emulator check
                || System.getProperties().getProperty("ro.kernel.qemu") == "1"
        return isRunningOnEmulator
    }

    private fun runningOnAndroidStudioEmulator(): Boolean {
        return Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("google/sdk_gphone")
                && Build.FINGERPRINT.endsWith(":user/release-keys")
                && Build.MANUFACTURER == "Google" && Build.PRODUCT.startsWith("sdk_gphone") && Build.BRAND == "google"
                && Build.MODEL.startsWith("sdk_gphone")
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use below method:

```
public static boolean isEmulator() {
    return Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("generic")
            || Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("unknown")
            || Build.MODEL.contains("google_sdk")
            || Build.MODEL.contains("Emulator")
            || Build.MODEL.contains("Android SDK built for x86")
            || Build.MANUFACTURER.contains("Genymotion")
            || (Build.BRAND.startsWith("generic") && Build.DEVICE.startsWith("generic"))
            || "google_sdk".equals(Build.PRODUCT);
}
```

Then in your `Activity` / `Application` class, call above method in `onCreate()` and handle your logic, as below:

```
if (isEmulator()) {
   // Emulator
} else {
   // Device
}
```

Comment: how is that an answer