# How to restrict CN1 app from running on Android Studio emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, codenameone

Due to app security concern I need to restrict a certain app from being able to run on emulator.
How can CN1 android build app be restricted from running on emulators like Android studio and Genymotion emulators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seemed like something easy to make so I added it in a [PR here](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/pull/3703). It should be available in next weeks update and would work using code like this in your start method:

```
if(getProperty("Emulator", "false").equals("true")) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Emulator not supported");
}
```

I based this change on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57960169/756809) and [this update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57958713/how-to-block-android-app-from-being-opened-on-emulators).

Comment: This will be a nice security feature

Answer (score 0):

Since emulators are rooted by default, adding [rooted device check](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/how-to-detect-jailbroken-or-rooted-device-and-hide-sensitive-data-in-background.html) at the start() or runApp() functions of the app is also a great solution.

```
public void start() {

  if (JailbreakDetect.isJailbreakDetectionSupported()) {

    if (JailbreakDetect.isJailbroken()) {
        Log.p("Device is rooted, killing the app...");
        Display.getInstance().exitApplication();

    } else {
      //proceed
    }
  } else {
      Log.p("Rooted device check unsupported");
      Display.getInstance().exitApplication();
  }
}
```

This is working perfectly in online emulators like [Appetize.io](https://appetize.io) and [Genymotion Cloud](https://cloud.geny.io)