# Is there any way to disable taking screenshot on emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, screenshot

So I have used following code to block to take screenshot

```
window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)
```

It is work fine on physical device but Android Studio Emulator is allow to take screenshot

[image]

Comment: Is there a problem?

Comment: @blackapps Yes because. I want to disable to take screenshot of my app in any ways. Suppose some one install's my app on any emulator and takes screenshot then what's the meaning of writing code to block screenshot which block only physical devices

Comment: Well jack already explained that you cannot prevent anything.

Comment: @blackapps So the solution is to block user to use the app on any emulator

Comment: What the fuss. A user can also take a picture of your smartphone when your app is running on it.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you made that particular button not work, there is no way to prevent the computer OS from taking a screenshot of an emulator it is running, but you could prevent your app from running on an emulator with high probability. See: [How can I detect when an Android application is running in the emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799097/how-can-i-detect-when-an-android-application-is-running-in-the-emulator)

If you still want to be able to do development on an emulator you could choose to only apply the emulator check in release builds.

Comment: So the solution is to block user to use the app on any emulator

Comment: That is what I would do. If you can run the app on an emulator then you can take a screenshot of it.