# Detect when running app on an Android Emulator in adobe air

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

does anybody know how to detect if a player is running the game on an Android Emulator such as Nox?
I was comparing the Capabilities of the players I know who play on Emulators vs the ones that play on real devices and I can't seem to spot any differences.

Comment: I don't think you can figure that from the inside **exactly** because the nature of emulator: it should look and feel as much Android for the running application as it possibly can. If it is at all possible to figure out, it should be somewhere in the folder structure of the local drive, some folders that is present on the emulator but doesn't exist on the real Android.

Comment: General reference: [How can I detect when an Android application is running in the emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2799097/2821954). This is of course if the emulator is built as "emulating an emulator", not "emulating a real device" which is harder or even impossible to detect.

Comment: The most common way is to access the local file structure to check the device ID, I remember there is a file that contains the device ID, device type and some unique code. However, that can also be spoofed by simply accessing an actual device and copy your file over to the emulator.