# Emulator Check is not working on NOX player in Android

Tags: android, security, android-emulator, nox

I have a requirement to the user cannot run the app on Emulator, SO for this, I have followed this link

https://github.com/mofneko/EmulatorDetector/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/nekolaboratory/EmulatorDetector.java

and other stuff also what is available on, But these conditions working fine for Android Studio Emulator, but on NOX player unable to detect,
This is a security vulnerability.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I detect when an Android application is running in the emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799097/how-can-i-detect-when-an-android-application-is-running-in-the-emulator)

Comment: No, I already also used these combinations, it is not working for nox player. @MorrisonChang

Comment: In the end an APK running on a client is completely dependent on API inputs which can be compromised (as described in the various answers linked). If the emulator fakes those inputs then the app doesn't know better. I don't know if any of the libraries check sensors/location data, but as even those can be faked any anti-piracy measures should be done server side.