# How to detect android app is running on Bluestacks emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, bluestacks

I need to disable app from running on emulators so I somehow combined answers of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799097/how-can-i-detect-when-an-android-application-is-running-in-the-emulator) question. It's working on most emulators but it can't detect blustacks. I can not find a robust way to detect blustacks as it has most of a real device properties.

[image]

I found [safeToRun](https://github.com/Safetorun/safe_to_run) library that using  `Build.BOOTLOADER == OsCheckConstants.UNKNOWN` to detect blustacks but I'm not sure that only this condition is enough to make sure the running device is a blustacks emulator and I'm afraid that some real devices return "unknown" as bootloader parameter.

it is worth mentioning that this block of code can't detect bluestacks too (glGetString returns null)

```
 try {
        String opengl = android.opengl.GLES20.glGetString(android.opengl.GLES20.GL_RENDERER);
        if (opengl != null) {
            if (opengl.contains("Bluestacks") ||
                    opengl.contains("Translator")
            )
                newRating += 10;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

any ideas or solutions?