# How this applications detects my emulator?

Tags: android, hide, emulation, root

I would really like to run a certain application on an Android emulator.

I've tried several emulators, particularly Genymotion, but it still doesn't work. The application detects that I am on a modified device and bans me.

I'm a beginner with Android; please guide me on where to start.

I've heard about modifying the build.prop, XprivacyLua, deleting certain files, etc... But I don't really know where to start.

My apologies if I've forgotten to specify any important information; please feel free to ask me.

Run a certain application on android emulator.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I detect when an Android application is running in the emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799097/how-can-i-detect-when-an-android-application-is-running-in-the-emulator)