# How to access Sprint NAI programmatically

Tags: android

Sprint Android Devices have a Network Access Identifier (NAI) which can be viewed by typing in ##data# (##3282#), View and Data Profile.  The NAI/UserName is the top line which looks like an email address.

Is it possible to access this information with an API programmatically?

[image: NAI/User Name Image]

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, this value should exist in the Android system property `persist.radio.cdmi.nai`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11623309/550808 for how to read Android system properties from your app.