# Toggle the debug Firebase Analytics prop at runtime on Android

Tags: android, adb, firebase-analytics

Motivation: toggle the debug Firebase Analytics property at runtime

I'm looking for a way to switch the debug on and off through the code like it's done through adb shell here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview

Already tried the methods that were advised here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11623309/6301831

But got this message:

```
Unable to set property "debug.firebase.analytics.app" to "com.pantos27.Basefook": connection failed; errno=13 (Permission denied)
```

running as root is not an option btw

Comment: I don't think you can achieve this without rooting your device. Maybe if your app app is platform signed.