# Android firebase analytics enable debug mode from code

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

To enable analytics debug on android, I have to execute following adb command:

```
adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app package_name
```

I am wondering, is it posible to enable this from code? 
I tried:

```
System.setProperty("debug.firebase.analytics.app",package_name)

System.getProperties().setProperty("debug.firebase.analytics.app",package_name)
```

but neither of those worked

Comment: Because there are two types of property in Android.

System level - we can get/set with command adb shell getprop/setprop.
In current process level - we can get/set with regular java System.getProperty()/setProperty().

I read it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750109/how-to-define-and-use-a-system-property-in-android-instrumentation-test/11623309