# Will TelephonyManger.getDeviceId() return device id for Tablets like Galaxy Tab...?

Tags: android, tablet-pc

I want to get the device id that will be unique for each Android device. I am presently developing for a Tablet device. Want to get unique device id and store the corresponding values...

So, i want to know whether Tablet devices will return a value if i use TelephonyManager.getDeviceId()...???Or is there any other value that is unique for each device???

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is *not* a duplicate question.  As it turns out, Google's CTS require that getPhoneType of TelephonyManager needs to be none and getDeviceId of TelephonyManager needs to be null for non-phone devices.

So to get IMEI, please try to use:

```
String imei = SystemProperties.get("ro.gsm.imei")
```

Unfortunately, SystemProperties is a non-public class in the Android OS, which means it isn't publicly available to regular applications.  Try looking at this post for help accessing it: [Where is android.os.SystemProperties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641111/where-is-android-os-systemproperties)

Answer (score 61):

**TelephonyManger.getDeviceId()** Returns the unique device ID, for example, the IMEI for GSM and the MEID or ESN for CDMA phones.

```
final TelephonyManager mTelephony = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);            
String myAndroidDeviceId = mTelephony.getDeviceId();
```

But i recommend to use:

**Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID** that returns the Android ID as an unique 64-bit hex string.

```
    String   myAndroidDeviceId = Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Sometimes **TelephonyManger.getDeviceId()** will return null, so to assure an unique id you will use this method:

```
public String getUniqueID(){    
    String myAndroidDeviceId = "";
    TelephonyManager mTelephony = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (mTelephony.getDeviceId() != null){
        myAndroidDeviceId = mTelephony.getDeviceId(); 
    }else{
         myAndroidDeviceId = Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID); 
    }
    return myAndroidDeviceId;
}
```

Comment: This solution has a problem: when the user switches to airplane mode, the telephony information disappears and the method will return the `Secure.ANDROID_ID` value. So the `getUniqueID()` method may be returning different values for different states of the same device.

Comment: @TedHopp, checked on several devices -  in airplane mode getUniqueID() method is returning the same value

Comment: why is ANDROID_ID returning 16 digit id for me, instead of 64 digit hex @Elenasys

Comment: So why not just use Secure.ANDROID_ID always?

Comment: ANDROID_ID is generated when user sets up the device. If the device is reset again, the id might change.

Comment: you should add try catch to avoid crash on Android 6+ runtime permission

Answer (score 2):

Since Android 8 everything's changed. You should use `Build.getSerial()`, to get the serial number of the device and add the permission `READ_PHONE_STATE`.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    serial = Build.getSerial(); // Requires permission READ_PHONE_STATE
} else {
    serial = Build.SERIAL; // Will return 'unknown' for device >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O
}
```

And get the IMEI or MEID this way:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    String imei = tm.getImei(); // Requires permission READ_PHONE_STATE
    serial = imei == null ? tm.getMeid() : imei; // Requires permission READ_PHONE_STATE
} else {
    serial = tm.getDeviceId(); // Requires permission READ_PHONE_STATE
}
```