# Android: deviceId null (TelephonyManager)

Tags: android, deviceid

I have a problem with TelephonyManager. DeviceId is null/blank.
This's my code. Where I wrong?

This is my java code

**RegistryActivity.java**

```
package android.tennis.app;

import android.tennis.library.UserFunctions;    
//import android.tennis.library.InfoPhoneAndroid;   
import android.content.Context;     
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;  
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;    

[...]   

public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {    

private String deviceID = null, androidID = null;   

@Override   
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     

    setContentView(R.layout.register);

    [..]    

    final TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    deviceID = telephonyManager.getDeviceId(); 

    [..]    

    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {

    [..]

    UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
    JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(nome, email, password, username, citta, data_di_nascita, cognome, deviceID);
}
```

When registerUser calls index.php, deviceId is null. Why?

**My manifest file is:**

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".DashboardActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!--  Login Activity -->
    <activity
        android:label="Login"
        android:name=".LoginActivity">

    </activity>

    <!--  Register Activity -->
    <activity
        android:label="Register New Account"
        android:name=".RegisterActivity"></activity>
</application>

<!-- Allow to connect with internet -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

I use an emulator. If I digit *#60#, the outupt is: 00000000

Comment: upload your manifest file's code as well.

Comment: on which device you are testing this code? means on mobile or tablet

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id)

Answer (score 3):

Not all android devices have 3G module, so not of them have telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
You should use some other uid

Comment: I also try :                 if (telephonyManager.getDeviceId() != null)
                    imeiid = telephonyManager.getDeviceId(); //*** use for mobiles
                else
                    imeiid = Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID); //*** use for tablets

Comment: I have solved! I use Log and the problem wasn't telephonyManager but json to send params to index.php

Comment: Nice. But you should stick to the code you've written in the comments, since deviceId can be null

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
public String getUniqueID(){    
    String myAndroidDeviceId = "";
    TelephonyManager mTelephony = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (mTelephony.getDeviceId() != null){
    myAndroidDeviceId = mTelephony.getDeviceId(); 
    }else{
     myAndroidDeviceId = Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID); 
    }
    return myAndroidDeviceId;
}
```

all credits to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8145184/1166727)