# Get IMEI in GenyMotion emulator

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, genymotion

Hi I'm developing an android application an runed it on genymotion emulator , in this application i need the device IMEI but i always get a null value the same logic works with AVD emulator or android smartphone

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
IMEI = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
```

with permission added to the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />﻿
```

Comment: What do you mean by same logic works with AVD emulator? Are you able to get IMEI number from AVD?

Answer (score 0):

The
    .getdeviceID()

is not reliable and yes it returns null if its an emulator. i found a link that might help you. Like an alternative

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802644/will-telephonymanger-getdeviceid-return-device-id-for-tablets-like-galaxy-tab)

[Link 3](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html)

Answer (score 0):

Genymotion emulator doesn't have IMEI code as there was an IMEI code if it's a real phone. But you can still generate a fake code with some specific method.