# Get serial number to Lenovo tablet

Tags: java, android, serial-number

I am trying to get serial number of my Lenovo Tab in android. I tried

```
Method get = c.getMethod("get", String.class, String.class);
serialnum = (String) (get.invoke(c, "ro.serialno", "unknown"));

serial = Build.SERIAL;
```

ro.serialno and Build.SERIAL is giving a value as 0123456789ABCDEF, but the serial in status-> about Tablet is HLB04JSJ and the printed serial number in the back side of the tab is also HLB04JSJ.

Any suggestions, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wow.  I've seen the serial number "0123456789ABCDEF" on a cheap no-name Chinese tablet, but I thought Lenovo was aiming a little higher than that.

Comment: Could you explain your underlying use case. Why are you trying to get that number?

Comment: I want to protect my apps, Just used for specific devices

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing the following?

```
TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String serial= tManager.getDeviceId();
```

Also include the following permission in your Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, unfortunately not worked (returned null)

Comment: Did you add the permission in your Manifest?

Comment: Yes i added this permission to my Manifest.

Comment: As a note, many lenovo tablets do not have a proper telephony_service in their ROM and so this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

please try this:

`String imei = SystemProperties.get("ro.gsm.imei")`

or take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802644/will-telephonymanger-getdeviceid-return-device-id-for-tablets-like-galaxy-tab)

Comment: That probably won't work. If the tablet is wifi-only, it won't have an imei.

Comment: systemproperties cannot be resolved, Is there any jar file to import systemproperties.

Comment: did you Enter *#06#  to be sure that your tablet has a serial number ?