# Eclipse does not recognize TelephonyProperties.PROPERTY_IMSI property

Tags: android

i search how can i get the IMSI number of android devices.
and i understand that i have to use SystemProperty class as it explained here:
[getting IMSI from android phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656558/getting-imsi-from-android-phone)
but when i am trying to pass this parameter, TelephonyProperties.PROPERTY_IMSI, to the SystemPropery class it shows me this error:
"cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641111/where-is-android-os-systemproperties

Answer (score 0):

The link you posted has the answer, those properties are not publicly accessible, you can use tricks to get to them but there is no guarantee that they will exist in all/future releases/devices.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5656732/329034