# can't import android.os.SystemProperties in Camera app

Tags: android

In camera.java, I need to get property in system. However, I can't import android.os.SystemProperties, compile camera always complains:

```
packages/apps/Camera/src/com/android/camera/Camera.java:53: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class SystemProperties
location: package android.os
import android.os.SystemProperties;
```

In the beginning of camera.java, I included:

```
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.MessageQueue;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.os.SystemProperties; /* (this is in line 53)*/
```

It seems SystemProperties is not in android.os package, but I have checked the frameworks source code, it's indeed in it.

This happen in camera app. I found many apps under packages/app dir using SystemProperties in this manner. It's really strange.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2641111/648313

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SystemProperties class is setted 'hide' annotation.
So you want to use this class in application layer,
you have to use refelection.

the definition of SystemProperties class is below.

```
package android.os;
/**
 * Gives access to the system properties store.  The system properties
 * store contains a list of string key-value pairs.
 *
 * {@hide}
 */
public class SystemProperties
```

Comment: Thanks. What's reflection, and how to use SystemProperties? The Mms app also just import it, but it's ok.

Comment: I found why! In Camera/Android.mk, LOCAL_SDK_VERSION := current, this prevent us using the HIDE interface. Comment this line will make compile pass.

Answer (score 3):

i have encounter the same problem as you have, and i use the code below, and solve the problem by using refelection. hope it would be help

```
//set SystemProperties as you want
public static void setProperty(String key, String value) {    
        try {    
            Class<?> c = Class.forName("android.os.SystemProperties");  
            Method set = c.getMethod("set", String.class, String.class);
            set.invoke(c, key, value );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "setProperty====exception=");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
    }
```