# Android - Can we capture system dialog in response of short code?

Tags: android

I'm trying to get currently active SIM number of user, I've tried other methods but didn't work, because number was not stored in the SIM.

Now I'm trying following method :

1) Dial a short code (*99#) : http://postimg.org/image/ijcqz92ap/

2) USSD code running...

3) And I get current SIM number : http://postimg.org/image/ggxeqtejj/

But the problem is that how can I capture the this system dialog, 
So that I get number from it ?

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570945/get-msisdn-from-the-sim-using-android

Comment: @Vektor88 That guy didn't answered about the 3rd step. I wanna capture this dialog !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**USSD is not yet supported on Android.**

There is a feature request for it, from Nov 12, 2008: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1285