# How to get the build.prop values?

Tags: android

How do I get the `build.prop` values that are found in `/system/build.prop` without root access? How do I edit them?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641111/where-is-android-os-systemproperties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does [`System.getProperty()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) help? As an alternative, you can execute `getprop` in a `Process` and retrieve its output.

Comment: Not sure... it does not retrieve properties in my `/system/build.prop`.

Comment: Do you see the property when you do `adb shell getprop` on the command prompt?

Comment: @BinoyBabu, As an alternative, you can execute `getprop` in a [Process](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Process.html) and get retrieve its output.

Comment: Thats exactly what I'm doing. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

You can probably consider using `SystemProperties.get("someKey")` as suggested by @kangear in your application using reflection like:

```
public String getSystemProperty(String key) {
    String value = null;

    try {
        value = (String) Class.forName("android.os.SystemProperties")
                .getMethod("get", String.class).invoke(null, key);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return value;
}
```

And then you can use it any where like:

```
getSystemProperty("someKey");
```

Answer (score 4):

Try This

```
static String GetFromBuildProp(String PropKey) {
    Process p;
    String propvalue = "";
    try {
        p = new ProcessBuilder("/system/bin/getprop", PropKey).redirectErrorStream(true).start();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            propvalue = line;
        }
        p.destroy();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return propvalue;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Such as:

`SystemProperties.get("ro.rksdk.version")`

Comment: Not seeing any such object!

Comment: This is rather for AOSP development than normal app development. Just import `android.os.SystemProperties`.

Answer (score 2):

use android.os.Build class, see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html, but you can not edit it without root access.

Answer (score 2):

I have checked multiple devices including some Samsung and LG devices as well as a Nexus 4, latest one was the Nvidia Shield Tablet with Android 6.0.
On all devices ll on /system/build.prop gave me this result(of course with varying size and date of build.prop):

> -rw-r--r-- root     root         3069 2015-10-13 21:48 build.prop

This means that anyone and any app without any permissions can read the file. Root would only be required for writing the non "ro."-values. You could just create a new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/system/build.prop")) and read all lines.

Advantages of this approach:

- no need for reflection (SystemProperties.get)
- no need to spawn a Process and executing getprop

Disadvantages:

- does not contain all system properties (some values e.g. are set at boot only available at runtime)
- not handy for getting a specific value compared to SystemProperties.get

Answer (score 1):

On the setting page of your file manager, set home as /system, then you could browse system folders and copy build.prop and paste to sdcard.  I'm still trying to root my phone but I have no problem tweaking on the way (no pun).

Answer (score -1):

To read properties using reflection on the hidden API :

```
static public String getprop(String key){
    try { Class c = Class.forName("android.os.SystemProperties");
        try { Method method = c.getDeclaredMethod("get", String.class);
            try { return (String) method.invoke(null, key);
            }  catch (IllegalAccessException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            catch (InvocationTargetException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    return null;
}
```

---

To edit them (Root required) manually, you should extract them with adb :

```
adb pull /system/build.prop
```

Edit them on the computer, then "install" the new build.prop :

```
adb push build.prop /sdcard/
adb shell
    mount -o rw,remount -t rootfs /system
    cp /sdcard/build.prop /system/
    chmod 644 /system/build.prop
```

Would be safer to keep an original build.prop copy.

Comment: Can you expand your comment on how to use reflection in this particular case?

Comment: SystemProperties.get() isn't accessible like other method, it has been hidden. In order to "unhide it", we must cast a neutral Class with Class.forName("android.os.SystemProperties"), extract it's method and invoke it.