# How to know exact model of Android device? (Like Samsung S7 'herolte')

Tags: java, android

I wonder how to find the exact model of a device as mentioned in the different analytics reports. Example: where to find on my device the 'herolte' of "Samsung S7 (herolte)"?

Comment: Please read the response below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995439/get-android-phone-model-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of device properties in `android.os.Build` : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build

check some of them that look suitable, like DISPLAY, BOARD, BRAND

Answer (score 0):

"herolte" can be retrieved from the `ro.build.product` system property (at least for Samsung devices):

```
public String getProduct() {
    Process p;
    String product = "";
    try {
        p = new ProcessBuilder("/system/bin/getprop", "ro.build.product").redirectErrorStream(true).start();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            product = line;
        }
        p.destroy();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return product;
}
```

If `ro.build.product` is not correct, you can run `adb shell getprop` and check the name of property you want.

I'm just not sure if `ro.build.product` is available for all brands. You mentioned Samsung S7.. `ro.build.product` works with Samsung devices.

**NOTE**

I used the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51705524/4860513) to build this one