# how to import android.os.SystemProperties

Tags: android

I am trying to use

```
SystemProperties.get();
```

but not able to import the `android.os.SystemProperties` package bit of googling tells me its hidden, is there any way around this ?

Comment: try reading this question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641111/where-is-android-os-systemproperties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641111/where-is-android-os-systemproperties)

Comment: How about the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564281/android-os-servicemanager-not-found-while-building

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`SystemProperties` is a hidden class that is only available to platform-level code. You could try to access it via reflection, but this is not recommended.

It is easy to confuse Android's `SystemProperties` class with the old-style Java way of doing properties, namely `java.lang.System.getProperty()`. Note that these are two totally separate systems. An important difference is that the Java mechanism works only within a given process, whereas the Android `SystemProperties` works across processes.

As an app developer, although you don't normally get a Java-based API into Android's Android `SystemProperties`, you can inspect the `SystemProperties` at the command-line using

```
adb shell getprop
```

Answer (score 2):

You can import **import android.os.Bundle;** and then you can access System properties using **System.getProperty("os.name");**

you can access any property by using System.getProperty('Property name');

Comment: SystemProperties.get(); I am still not able to use this but 
I am able to use  System.getProperty("os.name"); as you wrote

Comment: you can use **System.getProperties();** to access all properties

Comment: To get a particular property: use System.getProperties().getProperty()

Comment: This doesn't work for me. adb shell getprop shows that "wifi.interface" property is set to wlan0 but System.getProperty("wifi.interface") is null.

Comment: Not sure if this still works now...

Answer (score 0):

add 'layoutlib.jar" to your project's Java Build Path, and then, you can use "import android.os.SystemProperties;"

Comment: could you please provide a link for that layoutlib.jar?

Comment: this iink might help : http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/l/Downloadlayoutlibapi2220jar.htm

Answer (score 0):

if want to get device property,
for OS information you may check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html

just need to import android.os.Build;

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is, comment the

LOCAL_SDK_VERSION := current

in Android.mk. Using this way you can able to call hidden apis from the app

Answer (score -1):

One hacky way is to create your own `SystemProperties` class on your classpath so that your code compiles and works and then exclude it from your build. If class then exists on android device, it works fine. I do this quite often for very specific situations, but I wouldn't recommend this on commercial application for various versions and devices.

You can base it on [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/os/SystemProperties.java) class and just leave api that you need.

Example class:

```
package android.os;

public class SystemProperties {

    public static String get(String key) {
        return "";
    }

}
```

Then you just need exclude that class from your android/sourcesets/main in gradle file, for example:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            exclude 'android/**/*.java'
        }
    }
}
```