# How to programmatically get the IMSI-Number in Android

Tags: java, android

I tried the following code:

```
private String getImsi() {
   TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
   return mTelephonyMgr.getSubscriberId();
}

<uses-permission android:name='android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE' />
```

But it only returns null.
Is there any other way to obtain the IMSI with java in android?

Comment: Did you add `android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE` permission ?

Comment: try `mTelephonyMgr.getDeviceId();` ...

Comment: `getDeviceID()` returns the IMEI, but I need the imsi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String imei = android.os.SystemProperties.get(android.telephony.TelephonyProperties.PROPERTY_IMSI);
```

with permission

```
 android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
```

Since SystemProperties is a hidden class in Android, you can access it with reflection:

```
/**
 * Get the value for the given key.
 * @return an empty string if the key isn't found
 */
public static String get(Context context, String key) {
    String ret = "";

    try {
        ClassLoader cl = context.getClassLoader(); 
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Class SystemProperties = cl.loadClass("android.os.SystemProperties");

        //Parameters Types
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Class[] paramTypes= new Class[1];
        paramTypes[0]= String.class;

        Method get = SystemProperties.getMethod("get", paramTypes);

        //Parameters
        Object[] params = new Object[1];
        params[0] = new String(key);

        ret = (String) get.invoke(SystemProperties, params);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        ret = "";
        //TODO : Error handling
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but how can i add the android.os.SystemProperties? This cannot be resolved

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10409664/how-to-import-android-os-systemproperties u can reffer this answer

Comment: I think the refelction method does not work, or did i use it wrong? `String imsi = get(getApplicationContext(), "android.telephony.TelephonyProperties.PROPERTY_IMSI");`
I still get an empty string for the imsi

Comment: I was unable to find any mentions of class `android.telephony.TelephonyProperties`, only `com.android.internal.telephony.TelephonyProperties`, but there is no PROPERTY_IMSI constant there.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add this permission in the manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Edit:
ok, try use this one:

```
String myIMSI =
android.os.SystemProperties.get(android.telephony.TelephonyProperties.PROPERTY_IMSI);
```

SystemProperties it's an hidden class. try to check here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/os/SystemProperties.java

Comment: yeah i added the permission, i also edited the question, but thank you

Comment: is there an import for the `android.os.SystemProperties` ?

Comment: here's the class https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/os/SystemProperties.java take a look.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution works only for system applications:

```
    private String getIMSI(){
        telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(this.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        return telephonyManager.getSubscriberId();
    }
```

In AndroidManifest.xml add permissions:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE" />
```

The second permission is marked as system

Works in Android 9 (API 28).