# android - Compiling project with hidden class references

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to compile and build an apk for the CyanogenMod camera app on Android Studio. I have cloned the repo from [here](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Camera2). And I am trying to compile it.

Now a module in the project called `VideoModule.java` has references to classes that are not available in a public SDK.

For example `android.os.SystemProperties`, now after reading this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13059485/4801219) I am guessing that the particular class won't be available until I run the app on a live device **(Correct me if I am wrong)**

So I was wondering can the apk still be built on my system without the class being available in the SDK that I am using. Because it shows up as a compile time error in Android Studio.

That is 
`Cannot resolve symbol 'SystemProperties'`

Can I build the apk on my machine and deploy on a device to work on ? Is it even possible to build the camera app in Android Studio  ?

Comment: If your compilation error is limited  to the SystemProperties hidden class, then this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641111/where-is-android-os-systemproperties/5552950#5552950 may be useful

Comment: @ben75 Yeah but where do I put the class ? Should I put it in the same package as the VideoModule ? Or should I create a package called `com.etc.etc` as given in the answer ? And how do I use it ?

Comment: were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: @Marcelo Well it seems CM has a cmd line build process. See the build instructions on their site to get a better understanding. Basically the way I was describing here is not the correct method for building CM. Note: I have not tried the build process myself afterwards.