# How to get real device model in Android?

Tags: android, device

For example, on my Xperia mini phone,

- [Build.MODEL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#MODEL) returns **'st15i'**
- [Build.MANUFACTURER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#MANUFACTURER) returns **'Sony Ericsson'**

but I want to get **'Sony Ericsson xperia mini'** for this phone.

Is it possible?

Comment: check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#MODEL this one u may use `Build.MANUFACTURER` for model name and `Build.PRODUCT` for product name

Comment: thanks, Build.PRODUCT returns 'ST15i_1249-8388' and it's not what I want. I checked build.prop file in my phone and 'xperia mini' is under 'ro.semc.product.model'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that particular phone (and perhaps for many others SonyEricsson phones) you can get the real device name only by reading system property you have mentioned: `ro.semc.product.model`

Since `android.os.SystemProperties` class is hidden from public API you will need to use a reflection (or exec `getprop ro.semc.product.model` command and [grab its output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3772339/648313)):

```
public String getSonyEricssonDeviceName() {
  String model = getSystemProperty("ro.semc.product.model");
  return (model == null) ? "" : model;
}


private String getSystemProperty(String propName) {
  Class<?> clsSystemProperties = tryClassForName("android.os.SystemProperties");
  Method mtdGet = tryGetMethod(clsSystemProperties, "get", String.class);
  return tryInvoke(mtdGet, null, propName);
}

private Class<?> tryClassForName(String className) {
  try {
    return Class.forName(className);
  } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    return null;
  }
}

private Method tryGetMethod(Class<?> cls, String name, Class<?>... parameterTypes) {
  try {
    return cls.getDeclaredMethod(name, parameterTypes);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    return null;
  }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private <T> T tryInvoke(Method m, Object object, Object... args) {
  try {
    return (T) m.invoke(object, args);
  } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ST15I *is* the model code for the XPeria mini. So maybe you shoud use `Build.DEVICE`, ord build a correspondance base for the various codes to their names.

Comment: thanks, Build.DEVICE is same as Build.MODEL and returns 'st15i'.