# Doclava cannot find symbol SystemProperties (Android javadoc)

Tags: android, javadoc

I am running doclava (javadoc with the Android-style doclava doclet) on an existing codebase. At this stage I'm using javadoc via a simple command line, so this is not an Ant or Eclipse issue. I've paths to what seem to be all the necessary JAR and source files and have closed off large number of warnings already.  The codebase itself builds and runs fine.

However, I am left with some instances of one particular warning:

```
com.blah.blah.filename:42: error: cannot find symbol
import android.os.SystemProperties;
                 ^
  symbol:   class SystemProperties
  location: package android.os
```

Does anyone have any suggestions what I need to do to remove this last warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an answer of sorts.  See **[Where is android.os.SystemProperties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641111/where-is-android-os-systemproperties)**.

Essentially, **android.os.SystemProperies** is an internal class deliberately 'hidden' from the published SDK API and so really it shouldn't be in use.  Because it is hidden with **@hide** it's invisible to javadoc / doclava, hence the error.

The ideal answer to my original question would have been one that somehow pacified javadoc without having to mod the source code.  I don't think that is possible but if anyone out there knows different, I'd be grateful.