# The import android.os cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

I recently created a bug-free, fulling functioning android project. I even tested it on an android device, it worked fine.

I then closed eclipse and installed a few things from the SDK manager intended to speed up my emulator (intel x86 atom system image). After the downloads finished I opened eclipse and had errors on almost every line of my previously fine code.

It didn't recognize any of the android imports (hence the title). I couldn't open the android SDK manager because of:

`"Location of the Android SDK Manager has not been set up in the preferences."`

Then, after a bit more poking around a window popped up saying:

`"Multiple errors have occurred. java.lang.NullPointerException"`.

The XML doesn't have any error warnings, but the graphical display window is blank and at the bottom it says:

`"Eclipse is loading the SDK.  new_page.xml will refresh automatically once the process is finished."`

(its not loading anything, it has been that way for about an hour). I tried cleaning and rebuilding the project to no avail. I can't post pictures for some reason, my apologies. Some advice would be greatly appreciated! TLDR: I updated with the android SDKmanager and now nothing works!

Answer (score 0):

All public classes within the `android.os` package are marked with the [JavaDocs attribute `@hide`](https://code.google.com/p/doclava/wiki/JavadocTags#@hide), which, when applied to a package, class, method or field, removes that node and all of its children from the documentation.

Thus the namespace is not available to be imported, as there's nothing in it.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2641111/3063884), for example, another question about why the `android.os.SystemProperties` cannot be used in code (without Reflection).

Here's a link to the source indicating the use of the @hide attribute in the `SystemProperties` class: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/os/SystemProperties.java#26

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the same error the other day, actually same scenario and I just followed this guide and everything works again. http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html