# Getting SystemProperties.java class using android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system" attributes

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-source, android-make

I know that the [SystemProperties](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/eclair-release/core/java/android/os/SystemProperties.java) class won't be exported as part of the public SDK because of the `@hide` annotation.

What I've done:

1. Added the `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"` attributes on the `AndroidManifest.xml` file

   [image: manifest]
2. The application is signed with platform key

   [image: mk file]

and still get a compiling error...

**note**: I've already checked out the [where is os `systemproperties` question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641111/where-is-android-os-systemproperties).

But [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11123609/3360584) solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: Merely adding android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system" would not give you access to source files. You have to sign your apk with the ROM.

Comment: I've already signed my app.

Comment: For priv-app, better to use LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE := true instead of LOCAL_MODULE_PATH

Comment: @anhtuannd definitely. this is something I didn't know at that time.

Answer (score 0):

I've just added the below line on my Android.mk file, and it works

```
# Can only use LOCAL_PRIVATE_PLATFORM_APIS on Android 9+
ifneq (0, $(shell expr $(PLATFORM_VERSION) \>= 9))
LOCAL_PRIVATE_PLATFORM_APIS := true
endif
```